# How do I calculate how much RAM I have?

Tags: memory, c++

I'm running a simple C++ program to learn about dynamically allocated memory (`malloc`, `realloc` and `free`).

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
void *p = malloc(10); // Allocates 10 bytes in memory; `p` is a pointer to the first byte.

cout << "The value of the pointer p is:      " << p << endl;
```

This outputs something like this:

`The value of the pointer p is:      0x7fbf36c00080`

I'm aware the hex number is the memory location pointed to by `p`, which is the first memory location of this allocation.

When trying to calculate roughly how much RAM I have, I looked at the number of digits in that hex number (12 digits) and raised 16 to that power.

It turns out that 16^12 is roughly equal to 2.8x10^14 and since each memory location stores a byte, that means I have about 280 TERABYTES of RAM, even though I know I have 8 GB.

Where have I gone wrong in my calculation?

Comment: _"I looked at the number of digits in that hex number (12 digits) and raised 16 to that power"_ - why do  you think that would give you the correct result?

Comment: Additionally, why would your method work? What if you get a pointer in lower part of the memory?

Comment: Even if we disregard all the rest, what you have is not a physical memory location but a virtual memory location. In a 64-bit address space.

Comment: Well my thinking was that there are 12 digits, so there are about 12 digits worth of memory locations (or at least 11 digits). Since each digit can represent 16 different locations, 12 digits can represent 16^12. For the sake of argument, let's just say there is a very long street with a lot of houses. If someone lives in house number 5000 (in decimal), we know there are at least on the order of 1000 houses (possibly even 10000).

Comment: What you calculated was virtual address space. Using your analogy, just because someone is living at 5000, doesn't mean the developer has built house 10,000. They just have the land available TO build those houses when the time comes. Unfortunately, no one is buying the houses and most people live 0-1000, with some lonely old dude by himself at 5000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should study the concept of
[Virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory),
to understand that physical memory is mapped into the process's address space.

The fact that a 64-bit process may have pointers going up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1
does not mean that all this memory exists. The pointer points to a
[memory segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation)
which is mapped to physical memory somewhere in the computer.

Only the operating system knows how much memory you really have, so you
need to use its API for retrieving that amount.

As illustrated in my first Wikipedia link:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I wasn't aware of virtual memory.